# Is there Qt Creator documentation available in a ubuntu or debian package?

Tags: qt, documentation, qt-creator

From QtCreator, aka the Ubuntu SDK, I can ordinarily access documentation for classes such as QString and all QObjects, however, I can not access the documentation for classes such as:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-extending/projectexplorer.html

Is this documentation available anywhere for download, either in a deb or in any other form? I only periodically have the internet, so having a copy on my computer would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eike> AkivaAvraham: run "make -j1 docs" in your qt creator build directory

eike> and then in Qt Creator Options > Help > Documentation, add /shared/qtcreator/doc/qtcreator-dev.qch

eike> (that file is also in the shipped qt creator binaries from qt.io, but you have to register it manually